# NavigationBar isn't appear when using WebViewKit

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, wkwebview, navigationbar

I've a `ViewControllerWeb` to show a `WebView`. I need nav bar to show some options to user, so I need that NavigationBar is showed.

**Problem:** The navigation bar is not showed.

**ViewControllerWeb.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewControllerWeb : UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progress: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var url : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url!)!)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        self.webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didFinish")
        self.progress.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("didiFail")
        self.progress.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        print("webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate")
        self.progress.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didStartProvisionalNavigation")
        self.progress.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,
                 withError error: Error) {
        print("didFailProvisional")
        self.progress.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Result on simulator iPhone7**

[image]

The NavigationBar isn't showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present `ViewControllerWeb` with `UINavigationController`.

```
// Storyboard name
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
// Storyboard withIdentifier
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerWeb")
let navBarController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(navBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: In this way my `IBOutlets` aren't initialized.

Comment: You are using storyboard create ```viewcontroller``` like this.

```let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)```
```let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerWeb")```

Comment: Do you use Storyboard instantiateViewController way is working? @Augusto